# How do we indicate road/mtb/track specific questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Cycling is a broad topic with many sub-divisions. How are we going to indicate that a questions is MTB specific for example?

Are tags the way to go for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say definitely use tags. That's exactly what tags are for.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/134/merge-tags-road-and-road-bike

Answer (score 1):

Tags for sure: Mountain bike: mtb, Road bike: road.
For track/triathlon/cross etc, just create new tags when you ask a question

Comment: See also a question about 'road' and 'road bike' tags: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/134/merge-tags-road-and-road-bike