# Merge tags "road" and "road-bike"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging, tag-synonyms

It looks to me like everything tagged [road](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road) is actually about a road bike. Much of [road-bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-bike) is also tagged "road", even...  These tags look redundant to me, and it'd be nice to get everything that's about road bikes to be tagged consistently...

This is a taxonomy question, really...  Do we want to merge those and make "road-bike" a synonym for "road"?  It seems like on a bicycling site the "bike" part of the tag is redundant, so my personal opinion to leave "road" as the tag that stays around.  (besides, "road" is the more popular tag)

Do we think we'll need to be tagging about roads themselves (the surface bikes and other vehicles roll on)?  Would "roads" or "streets" or "asphalt" or "concrete" work for those if they do come up?

See also:

- [How do we indicate road/mtb/track specific questions?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/76)
- [How to manage duplicate tags](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-to-manage-duplicate-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site uses a lot of hyphenated tags, I'd suggest we keep that up and use road-bike, it's more immediately understandable that way.

I'd also suggest we convert the [mtb tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtb) to mountain-bike. We could continue this with touring-bike, folding-bike (we currently have folding-bicycle), and so on.

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably the way to go...

Comment: Tags edited for mountain-bike and for road-bike. It's weird when you go to the front page, it says edited by neilfein 1h ago for so many questions now! Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Road, but we could do with those little icons that specify certain tags on StackOverflow and other Exchange sites. That would help specify that Road means a road-bike, as opposed to the riding surface.

Comment: Should we make a feature request for little icons for a few of our tags?

Comment: I don't think they'd make special icons for a site that's as low-traffic as this, at least not yet. Unless this is easier than I think?

Comment: Open it up as a competition to the community.